# Android default font low quality on tablet

Tags: android, fonts

Default font in my app looks ugly at tablet (10.1 note) while it looks nice at phone (5-inch screen). In other apps on tablet font seems fine, but in my app it looks like missing some pixels. 
 
Screenshot to describe my problem: 
[image]

Comment: you have to maintain dimension.xml for all layout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.
Create android values folders that supports different screen sizes.

[image]

Here first folder for  7inch android devices that have ANDROID version 3.1 or less. second one is for 7inch devices that have android version greater than 3.1. 
naming convention sw600 means smallest width of 600. so this folder works for width size 600 to 720. So create **values-sw480dp** and **values-sw320** add values to dimens.xml file.

Android runtime automatically picks values from appropriate folder.

Create dimen.xml file inside each and every folder that supports different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

For solving this you need to add text sizes in `dimens.xml`  of `values-large` folder in your app.

Answer (score 1):

IN android you can create separate layouts and values for different screen sizes. So check in your project folder tree and find values-sw300dp, values-sw360dp etc... if you declared the screen size of that text view as 

`<TextView 
.......
android:textSize = "10sp"
>`

in the folder values-sw720dp edit the file dimens.xml to add new entry lets say "myheadingsize" and declare size as 20sp.

then change the textview as

`<TextView
...........
android:textSize="@dimens/myheadingsize"
>`

and for smaller devices edit corresponding dimens.xml to give smaller values for "myheadingsize"